# amount to move in a particular width

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics

I have a track of 2.5 units. I wanted my car to move every time such that the track is covered in 3 moves when it travels from extreme left to extreme right and accordingly it should calculate the X position to reach at every move at any point of the road.

```
Leftmost end of the track is at -1.45
Righmost is ar 1.05
```

As far as I can understand, `amountofmovement` should be `2.5/3` if track of width 2.5 is divided in three car moves from one end to the other but 2.5/3 will result in 0.83 which is not available to be moved in one particular direction since my range of track is from -1.45 to 1.05.

2.5/10 is what I found by hit and try but to understand it in a better way, what exactly shall be the concept?
Here is my code:

```
amountofmovement = 2.5/10;
```

which results in amount of movement = 0.25

```
this.transform.position = new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x - amountofmovement, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details? 
For example what works with 2.5/8? Is the car moving three times?

Comment: @Bio42: Updated, please check

Comment: You haven't posted when and where you update the position. I guess, it is just updated several times (as long as a key is pressed?) which ultimately sum up to a third ocassionally.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide us with the current state of your project, is the problem persistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't give you an code example, but what you did is perfectly right. 
When you Start at -1.45 and move the car three times by +0.83 you will reach +1.05. 
So you covered a distance of 2.5 in three steps.

Here are the x positions:

x (Start): -1.45

x (after first move): -0.62

x (after second move): 0.21

x (after third move/Finish): 1.05

(All values are rounded so please calculate them by yourself)